# Krakend is masking Client IP address

Tags: api, kubernetes, api-gateway, krakend

I have a python program that fetches the client IP using request.client.host headers and Fast API.
This program is running on a kubernetes pod(ip-pod).
I have another Gateway API implemented using KrakenD and this runs on another pod in kubernetes cluster.
The Kubernetes yaml files for both(ip-pod and KrakenD) have the property `externalTrafficPolicy: Local`
I am unable to retrieve the real IP of the user and this could be because KrakenD is not allowing the real IP to reach to the ip-pod.
I have tested the program by exposing the ip-pod to the internet using `type: LoadBalancer` and that way it gives the correct client IP. But when I use the KrakenD gateway, the IP is something different(private IP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the no-op with krakenD which will forward request to the backend

https://www.krakend.io/docs/endpoints/no-op/

you can check parameter forwarding config in your YAML of KrakenD also

```
"headers_to_pass":[  
      "*"
]
```

If you are getting client IP in header KrakenD will forward it to backend.

https://www.krakend.io/docs/endpoints/parameter-forwarding/#sending-all-client-headers-to-the-backends

Refrence

```
{
              "endpoint": "/api/v1/{uid}/user",
              "method": "GET",
              "headers_to_pass": [ "*" ],
              "querystring_params": [ "*" ],
              "output_encoding": "no-op",
              "concurrent_calls": 1,
              "backend": [
                  {
                      "url_pattern": "/api/{uid}/user",
                      "encoding": "no-op",
                      "host": [
                          "http://IP:Port"
                      ]
                  }
              ]
          }
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I view the output of the headers_to_pass? I have used the X-Forwarded-For header so that the source IP is kept intact.

Comment: in backedn writ simple test app or service which will print the request data to console and you can spin up pod and use that to check the headers getting pass at end

Comment: i am not 100% sure but here my docker registry user and image URI might be helpful to print data. https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/harshmanvar/http-https-echo use master one or use this github repo to build your custom one : https://github.com/harsh4870/docker-http-https-echo

Comment: use direct this docker : `mendhak/http-https-echo`, in my docker image, might be some changes will be there.